# Is there a forumla for this character's effective health?

Tags: linear-algebra

**Question**: How much total damage must I do to the character, compared to their maximum health (100%), when they've got this scaling damage reduction?

**Context**: In this game, there's a new character with a passive effect that has it so they take 1% less damage for every 2% missing HP. This appears to be a linear equation.

So, this means that for each 1% missing health, the remaining health is increased by .5% to determine "effective health" (ie how much total damage the rest of the health is worth).

**Set out the variables:** H = "current health %", E = "effective health %", and M = "missing health %", with "Max HP" being equal to 100%. Because all the variables are expressed in %, we have no need to clutter the equation.

**My thoughts**: Now, this would be an exceedingly simple, if this were just "He's missing 50% of his max hp (M = 50), so the rest of his hp (E) is simply increased by 25% (E = H*[1+M/2])."

However, it continues to increase in reduction as current hp is reduced.

I am only in like Algebra 1, and it is driving me crazy that I know there's a formula that would work, but I don't even know how to start making it.

Comment: Well, the effect of this variable damage reduction is nonlinear, but I think you have to consider something else: is damage applied continuously, or does it come in chunks? This makes a big difference if it’s the latter. If the character is at full health and takes that much or damage in a single hit, I would guess that this would drop the character immediately—the DR made no difference. If, on the other hand, you plink away at her a few HP at a time, the damage reduction is going to make a huge difference in the total damage that you need to do.

Comment: Yeah, that's going to make a big difference, but I want to know its maximum possible effective health, since everything else would be so variable as to be nonsensical as to try and think about in such a "hard coded" manner (most appropriate phrase I can think of).

Comment: [Alex Meigurg’s answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2374242/265466) will give you the maximum effect, when everything is updated continuously (barring things like fractional damage being truncated to the next-lowest integer, which can result in a character’s becoming unkillable in absurd edge cases). If you know the full HP and average damage per hit, though, it’s not too hard to come up with an estimate of the number of hits required to take down the character in the quantized case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the kind of question that calculus was designed to answer! I know that, unfortunately, you're not there yet, but you will be soon. :) In particular, the idea that 'little changes in this one variable' (health) are connected to 'little changes in this other variable' (damage modifier), is the central idea to all of calculus.

I'm going to quickly go through the work a Calculus student would do to solve this, and then try to explain it a bit intuitively for you.

Let $x$ be the actual health on a character, and let $y(x)$ be the 'effective' health for that. Then $dy/dx$ means the ratio of "how quickly do use up $y$" to "how quickly do you use up $x$". And since you're receiving $(1-x)/2$ protection, you only receive $1-(1-x)/2 = (x+1)/2$ of the damage, in other words meaning that $y$ changes $1/((x+1)/2) = 2/(x+1)$ as quickly. So

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{2}{x+1}$$
$$ \implies y = C + 2\log(x+1) $$

where that $\implies$ is the solving with the magic of calculus! There's one unknown constant, though, here written $C$. It means we have to have a starting point to connect $x$ and $y$: otherwise we're only stuck talking about how one changes. We know that when $x=0$ (the character is dead) that $y=0$ as well (the character is also /effectively/ dead). So plug in $x=0$ and $y=0$, and we see that $C = 0$. Then our relation is:

$$ y = 2\log(x+1) $$

If you plot this, you will see that indeed around $x=0$ (when the character is almost dead), that $y$ looks roughly like $y=2x$: all the health points there are worth about twice as much. And if you zoom in around $x=1$ (full health), you'll see that it looks like $y=x+b$, where $b$ is basically the "bonus health" the character will effectively get later -- but that right now the character is losing 1 effective health for 1 real health.

I wish I could explain why a logarithm gets into such a simple equation, but unfortunately that's a really complicated business. In the end it's actually one that's never explained in calculus courses, just taken on faith. :/ In the end it boils to one very special property of logarithms: if I plot the curve $y = \log x$, and pick a point on that curve and draw a tangent line, then the slope of that tangent line is inversely proportional to the x coordinate of the point I chose. The slope of that tangent line is important because it's telling you how tiny changes in x right there affect tiny changes in y. I hope that's at least a slightly satisfactory explanation! Comment if you have any other confusion! :)

Comment: You’re making an important assumption in this model: that both damage application and recalculation of damage reduction are done continuously. Games don’t generally work that way, so this calculation is in a sense the maximum benefit that the character will gain from the ability.

Comment: Thank you immensely for helping. Can you explain what the x and y are in the last equation? I've tried plugging it in to Desmos to see what happens...and...when x is 1, y is 0.602. I don't understand that. Shouldn't y be much higher than 1, being what I assumed to be the total effective health? And approaching 0, the two values don't seem to have the ~(y=2x) relation you claim.

Comment: @ amd That's true, I should have mentioned that. Thank you.
@SangoProductions I should have been clearer: that $\log$ is actually the natural logarithm, $\ln$; logarithm to base $e$. Desmos will default to $\log$ meaning logarithm to base 10. You should get that when $x=1$, $y=1.38$.

Comment: Cool. That looks more like what's to be expected. Thanks a lot.